# How can I copy a SQL Azure Database to a server on a different subscription?

Tags: azure

I'm trying to create a copy of a SQL Azure database. The source and destination servers are associated with two different subscriptions, but they are located in the same data-centre.

I've been reading [Copying Databases in Windows SQL Azure Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951624.aspx) and [How to: Copy Your Databases (Windows Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951631.aspx) for instructions on this, but I'm not sure if my scenario is covered.

I would like to use the `CREATE DATABASE Database1B AS COPY OF Database1A;` command, but I don't know what the implications are on the accounts used, or what I need to set up between the two databases before this command is possible.

Has anybody achieved this type of copy and can elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951631.aspx), you can copy databases between different servers on different subscriptions as long as the username and password are the same on both servers. You also need to make sure that the username on the source server has DBO privileges, and on the destination server has dbmanager privileges.